# Jquery form is not submitting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have page with form on it, I am trying to disable the button on submit with a custom disable message on it, and submit the form after using jquery.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="run"/>
<input type="submit" class="send" value="Save" data-attr-message="Sending..."/>
</form>
```

I have try both form submit or form[0] submit neither submits the form, I try logging the form, the form is logged correctly to console, and there are no errors in console when clicking submit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.send').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var button = $(this);
        var form = button.closest("form");
        button.prop('disabled', true);
        button.val($(this).attr('data-attr-message'));
        console.log(form); //Logs form fine
        form[0].submit();
        //  form.submit();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="run" />
  <input type="submit" class="send" value="Save" data-attr-message="Sending..." />
</form>
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: you need to change the last `input` to `button`

Comment: @holtc No, that's absolutely not necessary -> _"`<input>` elements of type `submit` are rendered as buttons. When the `click` event occurs (typically because the user clicked the button), the user agent attempts to submit the form to the server."_

Comment: @rykamol, I am not getting any error, after console.log it is doing nothing

Comment: I can not understand what do you mean with "after using jquery." phrase. you yourself decide to use jquery or not? what do you mean by that? in which condition do you want to enable button?

Comment: @hamid-davodi button will not be enabled, the form processing takes long time. This is to prevent people to keep clicking on the button

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not have an "action" and "method".

It should look like:

```
<form action = "http://example.com/backendScript" method = "POST">
```

Comment: this is not the issue browser defaults this to current page, and to GET. And if I don't have jquery the form submits just fine

Comment: The attributes are not required. A missing `action` is the same as `action="<this page>"`, and a missing `method` attribute is the same as `method="get"` -> https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#form-control-infrastructure-form-submission

Comment: Ohhh, my bad... have you tried using $.ajax, $post OR $.get to send the request? You will however need to populate the data element with a FormData object.

Answer (score -1):

if your goal is to "simulate" the time that it takes to send data, and you want to see the button to be disabled until that time, one way is to use "setTimeout()" method of javascript. you do not need to use "e.preventDefault()" because it prevent the form from submitting. I posted the code below that I think does what you expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.send').click(function(e) {

          var button = $(this);
          var form = button.closest("form");
          button.prop('disabled', true);
          button.val($(this).attr('data-attr-message'));
        setTimeout(function() {
            
            form.submit();
        }, 1000)  
      
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
   
<form action="submit.html">
<input type="text" name="run"/>
<input type="submit" class="send" value="Save" data-attr-message="Sending..."/>
</form>
   

   <script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

> the "submit.html" is simply an html file with a message that you can add to your folder yourself to see that the form is submitting.

Comment: I am not trying to simulate anything

Comment: I mean that you want to see the "time" that it takes. but in each case the form is submitting with the code I posted.

Comment: Did you even try this? Doesn't do what you suggest it should. There is no delay and disabling in the click event handler is not the same as preventing default

Comment: you could try the "Run code snippet" button in the above to see that it disables the button and show the message for one second, after that one second it goes to "submit.html" page, you should add it for your files to see the submission. just create a "submit.html" file in the same folder and put a "h1" tag with a message in it.